# "Alcanzar máxima reflejado" meaning

Tags: vocabulario

> En el cuadro *Los fusilamientos del 3 de mayo*, inspirado en los acontecimientos de 1808 durante la Guerra de Independencia, el arte de Goya alcanzó la máxima reflejado.

No entiendo el significado de "la máxima reflejado". Creo que es mejor usar expresividad en lugar de reflejado, no?

Comment: Sounds weird. Could you add a link to the source of that paragraph? I want to check it within its context, and see if there is something after it too.

Comment: I think that is a typo or a bad translation from English. I can't find any occurrences of _la máxima reflejado_ on Internet, except in a sentence (not about Goya) were _reflejado_ is part of a subordinated sentence that follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La expresión "la máxima reflejado" no tiene sentido. Como dicen en los comentarios debe tratarse de un error de tipeo. Reemplazar la palabra "reflejado" por "expresividad" sí genera una oración correcta, pero habría que ver si efectivamente la afirmación contiene verdad (¿Goya realmente alcanzó la máxima expresividad en ese cuadro, y no en otro?).